# Input | Get the new value set by a JavaScript function into a Controller public function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have created a CRUD to edit existing table rows.

One of its input contain already a value="19.00" saved at the creation of the row  :

```
<input type="number" step="1" title="Prix" class="form-control" name="productprice" id="productprice" value="19.00">
```

I'm overriding the value in my CRUD with a javascript function when the value of a select list is changed by the user, for example if one of the product property is changed and impact the price :

```
$('#form').on('change', function() {

var d1 = document.getElementById('ordersdetailproducttype_ID').value; // producttypeID
// console.log('producttype ID:', d1);
var d2 = document.getElementById('ordersdetailproductname').value; // productnameID
// console.log('product ID:', d2);
    var d3 = document.getElementById('ordersdetaildessertservingID').value; // dessertservingID
// console.log('Servings:', d3);
var pl1 = document.getElementById('ordersdetailID_portion').value; // partyloafportionID
// console.log('pl1:', pl1);
var pl2 = document.getElementById('ordersdetailpartyloafweightID').value; // partyloafweightID
// console.log('pl2:', pl2);

if (d1 == '' && d2 == '' && d3 == '' && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#ordersdetailproductprice').val('0.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 1 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#ordersdetailproductprice').val('19.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 2 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#ordersdetailproductprice').val('24.00'); }
...
```

In this case the user sees the new value (price) into the input,

[image: picture]

value which I don't see by inspecting the element structure :

```
<div class="form-group header-group-0 " id="form-group-productprice" style="display: block;">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Prix
        </label>

<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="number" step="1" title="Prix" class="form-control" name="productprice" id="productprice" value="19.00">
    <div class="text-danger"></div>
    <p class="help-block"></p>
</div>
```

If I look at the element with the inspector, I can see that the value of the input is still

```
value="19.00"
```

I need to retrieve the new value set by my JavaScript function in my controller in order to be able to update accordingly my table row column with a controller public function.

First time I'm confronted with this kind of issue, I have no clue how to solve this. Would appreciate your expertise. Thanks, Marc

Comment: How is this related to PHP or Laravel? What have you tried to debug the problem further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION AJAX CALL IN JS SCRIPT :

```
...
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 2 && pl2 == 2) { $('#productprice').val('59.00'); }
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 3 && pl2 == 3) { $('#productprice').val('69.00'); }
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 4 && pl2 == 4) { $('#productprice').val('79.00'); }
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 4 && pl2 == 5) { $('#productprice').val('89.00'); }

var rowID = rowid;
var orderID = $('#orderID').val();
var productprice_new = $('#productprice').val();
console.log(productprice_new,rowID,orderID);

$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: '/assets/ajax/ajaxupdate.php',
data:  {
        'rowid' : rowid,
        'orderID' : orderID,
        'productprice_new' : productprice_new,
        },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('worked!');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a default value for `input` field, changing it via `val()` wouldn't impact it.

You need to use `attr()`, so instead of lines like:

```
$('#ordersdetailproductprice').val('0.00');
```

Use:

```
$('#ordersdetailproductprice').attr('value', '0.00');
```

And then you can easily fetch the input value to send to your Controller (via AJAX I believe) as:

```
let value = $('#ordersdetailproductprice').val();
```

*I hope it helps you*

Comment: thanks appreciate, this is the way I thought to solve it, I'm working on it since it is new land for me, but get back to you asap to inform about outcome.

Comment: change the attr. value was finally not the solution, since the value wasn't submitted. But I found the solution with a Ajax call, Thanks again.

Comment: congrats! you should post the solution yourself and mark it accepted so that we could close this thread