# Pass jquery chosen value to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to pass the select value from the following script to PHP :

```
$(window).bind('change', function() {

// Get the values from the select boxes

var d1 = $('#producttype_ID').val(); // producttypeID
// console.log('producttype ID:', d1);
var d2 = $('#productname').val();
// console.log('product ID:', d2);
var d3 = $('#dessertservingID').val(); // dessertservingID
// console.log('Servings:', d3);
var pl1 = $('#ID_portion').val(); // partyloafportionID
// console.log('pl1:', pl1);
var pl2 = $('#partyloafweightID').val(); // partyloafweightID
// console.log('pl2:', pl2);

if (d1 == '' && d2 == '' && d3 == '' && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('0.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 1 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('19.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 2 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('24.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 3 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('32.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 4 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('40.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 5 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('48.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 6 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('65.00'); }
else if (d3 == 7 && d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('80.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 8 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('98.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 9 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('115.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 10 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('130.00'); }
else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 11 && pl1 == '' && pl2 == '') { $('#productprice').val('170.00'); }
})
```

If for example the last value is chosen (170.00), how can I catch this value into my ajax date :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myfile.php',
    data: { #productprice: value }
});
```

So that I can pass it to my PHP script with :

```
$productprice = $_POST['productprice'];
```

Thanks for you expertise, Cheers, Marc

Update :

Tried this :

```
....
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 4 && pl2 == 5) { $('#productprice').val('89.00'); }

})

var productpricenew = $('#productprice').val();
console.log(productpricenew);

    $.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: 'AdminMesCommandesNonTraiteesController.php',
data: { key : productpricenew },
    success: function (data) {
        // alert(data);
    }
})
```

but the value "$('#productprice').val();" returned on console is Null. So I need to find a way to catch the chosen value from the else if loop.

Comment: try this `data: { "productprice": $('#productprice').val() }`

Comment: Is there any connection to your prior question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018896/input-get-the-new-value-set-by-a-javascript-function-into-a-controller-public?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to find a solution to the prior question | issue and I thought it is better for me, since I'm not omniscient and not an expert, to "cut" my issue in small pieces I can handle. If you don't mind...

Comment: @bassxzero, thank for your suggestion. I tried this just after )} my else if loop :

 var productpricenew = $('#productprice').val();
 console.log(productpricenew);

     $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'AdminMesCommandesNonTraiteesController.php',
    data: { key : productpricenew },
        success: function (data) {
            // alert(data);
        }

but the value returned to the console is null, so still looking how to "catch" the chosen value from the else if loop, since "$('#productprice').val();" don't catch it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION :

I found the solution (partially since I haven't found yet the way to pass those value to my Controller, that will be part of another question) :

Ajax Call :

```
...
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 2 && pl2 == 2) { $('#productprice').val('59.00'); }
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 3 && pl2 == 3) { $('#productprice').val('69.00'); }
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 4 && pl2 == 4) { $('#productprice').val('79.00'); }
else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 27 && d3 == '' && pl1 == 4 && pl2 == 5) { $('#productprice').val('89.00'); }

var rowID = rowid;
var orderID = $('#orderID').val();
var productprice_new = $('#productprice').val();
console.log(productprice_new,rowID,orderID);

$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: '/assets/ajax/ajaxupdate.php',
data:  {
        'rowid' : rowid,
        'orderID' : orderID,
        'productprice_new' : productprice_new,
        },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('worked!');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
})
```

Return the 3 values correctely